# How to click on a table cell containing known text?

Tags: watir

Using Watir, I want to click on a table cell containing the text "ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait"

The HTML is:

```
<span onclick="javascript:showListMembers(343);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;">ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait</span>
```

What is the correct Watir statement?

Comment: If it's always "showListMembers(343);" you can execute the javascript statement of "showListMembers(343);" to the same effect.

Comment: Did you try `browser.span(:text => "ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait").click` or `browser.span(:onclick => "javascript:showListMembers(343);").click`?

Comment: It's not always 343. The row below (created earlier in time) is 342. @Joseph: First answer worked. Second: error = `onclick is an unknown way of finding a  element (javascript:showListMembers(343);)`

Comment: In my previous comment, `@Joseph` should be `@orde`

Comment: Not sure why you got an `onclick is an unknown way` error, but you can (depending on your specific needs) use a regex on the locator value.  For example: `browser.span(:onclick => /showListMembers\(\d+\)).click`

Comment: @orde, `:onclick` is only valid as a locator in Watir-WebDriver. It is not supported in Watir-Classic. So the exception is likely due to using Watir-Classic.

Comment: Ahhh...I'm pretty much all watir-webdriver, all the time now.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, I'm using Watir. I've just seen the recommendation in your book today: `Getting help - Specifying the gem being used helps ensure that solutions are applicable.` Another useful bit: `Watir - This gem is just a loader. Based on the browser that you want to run and your operating system, the Watir gem will load either Watir-Classic or Watir-Webdriver.` I never knew that before. I used to comment out/in Watir or Watir-WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

```
matches = b.spans(:text => "ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait")
```

Use the plural method unless you're sure there's only one possible match. You can also do regex stuff

```
matches = b.spans(:text => /ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait/)
```

Span elements aren't table cells in the proper sense. Table cells don't normally have useful metatags